# Visual Studio 2010 nuget error: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, nuget

Whenever I'm trying to install something or even just list the packages I get this error "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

I tried [this](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1623) solution from Codeplex with no luck.

I use the [latest version of Nuget](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c).

I also tried different options in devenv.exe.config like this:

```
<servicePointManager  checkCertificateName="false"    checkCertificateRevocationList="false"/>
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

- Go to VS2010 → Tools → Library Package Manager → Package Manager Settings.
- Choose Package Manager → Package Sources.
- Add a new package source as:

  - Name: `NugetSource`
  - Source: http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/
- Move Up the newly added package source to first position.
- UnCheck existing "Nuget official package source"
- Restart VS2010.

Comment: Thank you, It also worked for me, on Visual Studio 2013 Express, behind corporate proxy/firewall.

Just wanted to add, that It didn't required me to Restart Visual studio either. It will just work.

Answer (score 23):

Go to https://nuget.org/ and get its certificate.

For example, if you're using Firefox: after opening nuget site - click site's icon on the left side of address bar, click 'More Information', and on the Security tab there should be 'Web-site identity' section with 'View certificate' button. Click there, in the opened dialog select Details tab - there you should see chain for *.nuget.org. Click button 'Export' at the bottom and save certificate to the file (add `.cer` extension manually, because dialog won't do it for you).

Now you need to setup you system so that it will trust the certificate. Press Win+R (Run dialog will be opened) -> type `mmc` there and run it (with admin privileges if you have UAC turned on). There select File -> Add or remove snapin... -> select Certificates on the left, in the dialog select `Computer account` and `Local computer`. Click OK - the tree will have `Certificates` node in the `Console root`. Open it and file folder `Trusted People`. From its context menu select All tasks -> Import... -> Select file that you have exported before and import it.

Everything should be working fine.

Comment: In the browser I don't se the sertificate errors now, but my VS still could not install the package.

Comment: @Akim I don't have errors either, but I've been seeing the same error until I added nuget certificate to TrustedPeople. Probably it is not required for establishing connection and viewing site contents, but required to install binaries from the site to your box.

Comment: For two days, I've been looking for the cause and tried everything. Finally, your solution is the only one that works on my VS 2019. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing that worked for me on VS 2017

Comment: This worked in VS 2022 too for me, thanks!

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: New computer with a new install of Windows 11 and just visiting NuGet.org in Edge worked for me. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 12):

We had the same issue in work, and we resolved this by dropping the secure socket, **Https** -> **http**.  This means you can use the V2 URL http://nuget.org/api/v2/.

Possibly an issue getting rid of the secure socket, but the above URL (http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/) is also unsecure.

Comment: When I try that, I get a http 404.

Comment: Which URL are you trying? the first? I just tried that one and it's working fine

Answer (score 8):

There's apparently an issue with the SSL cert on go.microsoft.com. Change the package source url to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/ and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 8):

Related: *ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the https scheme*

If you've previously had Fiddler open, you might well have a certificate for nuget.org that is invalid.

If so, open up MMC, add the Certificates snapin (current User) and remove nuget.org from the Personal store.

[image: Example certificate to remove]

Due to Nuget keeping a handle to this cert (seemingly) you will have to restart Visual Studio. Afterwards, you should have a good time.

Comment: This fixed it for me, although the cert wasn't named nuget.org, deleted all with nuget and myget in the name though. Many thanks for posting your finding Andy

Answer (score 4):

Go to VS2012 -> Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings 
Choose Package Manager -> Package Sources.

1. Add a new package source as: Name= NugetSource Source= http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc/
2. Move Up the newly added package source to first position.
3. UnCheck existing "Nuget official package source"
4. Restart VS2012.

This is working on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

If nothing from above works, try this....

Try pasting the following into a .reg file and run it. Then try running your NuGet command (no reboot required).

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
> "SchUseStrongCrypto"=dword:00000001

Ran into this issue because TLS1.2 was not enabled (similar to Tony's response). Using http does not fix the situation because NuGet redirects to https now that TLS1.2 is enforced.

thanks to "neoscribe"

Answer (score 2):

As of today 21-Jan-2015, the correct url is https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/. The www is required or the certificate fails. Do NOT fall back to http because you are opening your code and all of its consumers to a nasty MITM vector.

Comment: This also worked for me apart from that FeedService url.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was solved by clearing the nuget cache (and restarting VS)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by dropping the secure socket, `https` **`->`** `http`. 
Go to <kbd>**Tools**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Nuget Package Manager**</kbd> `->` <kbd>**Package Sources**</kbd>, then add a new source, but without `https`:

This means **http://nuget.org/api/v2/**.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove https in Local machine settings for Nuget and added (http) it to user level in  Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings Choose Package Manager -> Package Sources.

Answer (score 0):

i have had no luck with any method related to Visual Studio. Not updating everything, not manually adding the Root Certificate of https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json to windows, etc. How I fixed it:

`nuget restore MySolution.sln`

Download nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/downloads).