# NuGet.targets (100): Unable to find version '4.0.20710.0' of package

Tags: nuget

I am using VS 2012 and TFS 2010.
Recently my PC was upgraded from windows 7 to windows 8.
When I unloaded my application from TFS and tried to build it for deployment to the test server, I got these error messages. 
Underneath those error messages I got the warning (repeated many times): "EXEC : warning : The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel."
How do I get a clean build?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer from ChristianDev on SO, which is to go to 
Tools -> Nuget Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Package Manager -> Package Sources and then add a new Available package source, replacing https with http.
There may be a price to pay by not using a secure url, but it worked.
See [Visual Studio 2010 nuget error: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8972497/visual-studio-2010-nuget-error-the-underlying-connection-was-closed-could-not)

I should add that I would prefer a better solution.